# Como encontrar um link dentro de um arquivo html e trocar por outro link?

Tags: php

Até agora só consegui saber se parte do link existe no arquivo, mas não sei como fazer a troca. Meu código e esse:

```
$nomeArquivo = $_POST['nomeArquivo'];


foreach ($arquivos as $a){
$aq = fopen($a,"r+");
while (!feof($aq)){
    $le = fgets($aq);

    if(preg_match("/arquivo.txt/",$le)){

        //realizar troca
       //salvar arquivo
    }

}
fclose($aq);
}
```

Comment: Poderia ser mais claro em sua dúvida? Estou sem entender

Comment: Vi que é um novo usuário, portanto não leve isto para o lado pessoal, mas considere em alterar ou detalhar as funções/variaveis. É extremamente desgastante ficar procurando o que seria `$le`, `$a`, `$aq` e coisas que nunca são usadas, por exemplo `$nomeArquivo`, o que confunde mais ainda. Numa próxima publicação considere dar mais detalhes, essencialmente dentro do próprio código, com pequenas alterações, assim poderá ter respostas ainda melhores e mais rápido. :)

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas , farei isso da próxima vez . muito obrigado pela disposição em me ajudar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para realizar a substituição pode usar o `str_replace` ou `preg_replace`.

Neste caso basta alterar para:

```
<?php
//...
    if(preg_match("/arquivo.txt/",$le)){

    $conteudo = str_replace("arquivo.txt", "novo_arquivo.txt", $le);
    // Alternativa: preg_replace("/\barquivo.txt\b/", "novo_arquivo.txt", $le);
    // Substitui o arquivo.txt por novo_arquivo.txt
    fwrite($aq, $conteudo);
    // Escreve o conteúdo editado.

    }
//..
?>
```

**Solução ideal:**

Abandone o `fopen`, será mais fácil e não terá tanta perda de performance.

```
<?php
//...

foreach ($arquivos as $caminho){

$conteudoArquivo = file_get_contents($caminho);
// Isso irá pegar todo o conteudo do arquivo

  if(preg_match("/arquivo.txt/", $conteudoArquivo)){
  // Se existir arquivo.txt

  $conteudoEditado = str_replace("arquivo.txt", "novo_arquivo.txt", $conteudoArquivo);
  // Novo $conteudoEditado terá a alteração

  file_put_contents($caminho, $conteudoEditado);
  // Salva as alterações
  }

}
//..
?>
```

**Importante (função `feof()`):**

Existem alguns casos onde o `feof()` pode criar um loop infinito, inclusive existem exemplos na documentação do PHP, que pode ser acessado [clicando aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.feof.php).

Comment: Montei o código , mais esta dando este erro :Warning: preg_replace(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in /var/www/php/teste.php on line 7 vc sabe o que pode ser ?  .coloquei todo o código nesse site https://codeshare.io/ZQg7c

Comment: Substitua por `str_replace`.

Comment: Se usar o `preg_replace` utilize preg_replace("/\barquivo.txt\b/", "novo_arquivo.txt", $le), note o `/\b_______\b/`  para restringir a palavra. Desculpe o equivoco na função. :[

Comment: Cara , agora deu certo , só que ele mantem o link antigo  e na linha debaixo substitui corretamente, e depois da substituição tudo que existia abaixo do arquivo ele apaga , teria alguma forma de manter os registros abaixo e ele apagar somente o link antigo ?

Comment: Isso acontece porque o fgets lê linha por linha. Irei reescrever para essa situação.

Comment: Editei a publicação. ;]

Comment: Cara , deus te abençoe , muito obrigado pela atenção

Answer (score 0):

Não está claro pois dependendo do que precisa ser feito há formas diversas para resolver.

Por exemplo, se quer apenas trocar uma string específica em todos os links, pode usar `str_replace()` e salvar com `file_put_contents()`. Nem precisaria abrir com `fopen()` e buscar com `regex`. Mas como disse, depende do que realmente precisa ser feito.

Exemplo, caso queira apenas substituir uma string por outra dentro do conteúdo de um arquivo:

```
file_put_contents(str_replace('nome-antigo.txt', 'nome-novo.txt', file_get_contents($caminho_do_arquivo)));
```

Comment: O que e mais recomendado , pois quero criar um upload de arquivos , e quando enviar esse arquivo o nome do arquivo irá substituir na página o nome do arquivo antigo ,por isso estou tentando fazer isso com variáveis por enquanto , pra depois fazer essa outra parte

Comment: está muito confuso.. Então não tem nada a ver com ler  conteúdo do arquivo. O que você quer é mudar o nome dos arquivos. É isso?

Comment: Cara tem sim , e que onde eu trabalho usamos uma intranet muito antiga , e em uma universidade , temos uma pagina de downloads de manuais de teses , esse mesmo link esta disponível em varias paginas do sistema , o que quero fazer e quando fazer o upload de um novo manual , esse mesmo link se atualize nas outras paginas automático .como o sistema e antigo para não mexer nas outras paginas quando postamos uma nova tese .substituímos  o arquivo antigo pelo novo, mais estamos tendo problemas em relação a cache nos navegadores dos clientes

Comment: Então vc precisa ler todos os arquivos html desse site de intranet e substituir os links antigos pelo link novo. É isso? Deixe isso melhor detalhado na pergunta.

Comment: Sim e isso mesmo ,pra se ter uma ideia um único manual esta disponível em 11 paginas diferentes  , quero passar as paginas especificas ou o diretório e o script fazer essa alteração dos links . Graças a ajuda de vcs  ,estou quase conseguindo , já montei o formulário onde coloco o nome do arquivo e o  script busca esse link em outra pagina e altera .https://codeshare.io/Miiwu  , existe uma maneira melhor de se fazer isso ?

Comment: descreva esses detalhes  na pergunta...